# Thompson's group F and T

Tags: group-theory

This question is about Thompson's groups $F$ and $T$. I am not convinced how every element of $F$ gives an element of $T$?

As per the definition, Thompson group $F$ is the group of all piecewise linear homeomorphisms of $[0,1]$ to itself which are differentiable except at a finitely many rational dyadic points and in the interval of differentiability the derivative is a power of 2 and Thompson's group $T$ is the group all piecewise linear homeomorphisms of $S^1$ to itself that maps images of dyadic rationals to images of dyadic rationals that are differentiable except at finitely many images of dyadic rationals and at the interval of differentiability the derivative is a power of 2.

If we consider $[0,1]$ as $S^1$ by identifying the endpoints, that is by the map $[0,1] \rightarrow S^1$ mapping $x \mapsto e^{2\pi ix}$ and then descending to $S^1$, every element of $F$ gives a piecewise linear homeomorphism of $S^1$ to itself which maps images of dyadic rationals to images of dyadic rationals.But I dnt know, how the derivative is still a power of $2$? If $f\in F$, then the map $[x] \mapsto e^{2\pi i f(x)}$ gives such a map but I dnt know the derivative will be a power of 2 if the derivative of $f$ is a power of 2?

Comment: Let's start with the fact that derivative (at given point) is not a number. But rather a linear operator. This is important because derivatives on $S^1$ (as a manifold) are not straightforward. You need a differential structure on $S^1$, you need tangent space and then maybe apply [pushforward](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_(differential))?

Comment: I am not familiar with the manifold theory. Can you elaborate little more. Then what does it mean to be the derivative is a power of 2 for an element in T? Also, what is a piecewise linear function on $S^1$?

Comment: This is not my area of expertise as well (hence the comment only). Maybe someone else understands these topics better. Anyway if $f:M\to N$ is a function then the derivative at $x\in M$ is (if exists) a certain linear operator $T_xM\to T_{f(x)}N$ between tangent spaces satisfying certain approximation properties. Now tangent spaces have the same dimension as the underlying manifold. So in dimension $1$ (your case) linear operators are of the form $f(x)=\lambda x$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. I believe that this $\lambda$ is what the author refers to when he talks about "derivative".

Comment: Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Also in order to talk about piecewise linear functions on manifolds you need a piecewise linear structure on both manifolds. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_manifold Again this is not straightforward.

Comment: Perhaps all of that somehow gets simplified in $S^1$ case but I'm not really sure. What is the book/article/paper you are studying?

Comment: http://people.math.binghamton.edu/matt/thompson/cfp.pdf  page number 11

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $T$ just uses $S^1$ as equal $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$. So by definition $F$ is just the stabilizer of $0=1$ in the action of $T$ on $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$, and there is nothing to check (one does not use the circle as model for $S^1$).

Comment: But in the lecture notes http://people.math.binghamton.edu/matt/thompson/cfp.pdf the definition of T is different. First $S^1$ is considered as $[0,1]$ with endpoints identified.

Comment: Yes, $[0,1]$ with endpoints identified, this is just the same as $\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{Z}$.